# Assigning property of StdClass to a variable

Tags: php

A bit of a php noob - I have some php code which I downloaded that calculates moon rise and set times and returns:

```
 object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["moonrise"]=> int(1309219860) ["moonset"]=> int(1309281240) } int(1309219860)
```

With some messing around I managed to get the moonrise assigned to a variable so I can use it - the problem is it got a int in it. How do I convert this to a integer so I can use it later?

```
$times = (Moon::calculateMoonTimes(6, 28, 2011, 43.654406, -3.320222));
$rise = $times->moonrise;
echo var_dump($rise);
```

This is returned:

```
int(1309219860)
```

Comment: This is the exact thing you want to have. `var_dump` just print it this way so you know which type it is. Use `echo $rise;` and you will have a plain integer.

Comment: Tobias, you should put that as an answer, you are entirely correct.

Comment: Ahh - I was so close! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/var_dump) documentation for `var_dump()`:

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

For simply displaying the value, you can use `echo` instead of `var_dump()`:

```
$times = (Moon::calculateMoonTimes(6, 28, 2011, 43.654406, -3.320222));
$rise = $times->moonrise;
echo $rise;
```

Also, if you want to ignore the decimal values and just return an integer, you can use [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval)

```
$rise = intval($times->moonrise);
echo $rise;
```

Hope this helps!